# python-keybinder and right hotkey string

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Python-keybinder is used to set global hotkeys in my program. GtkToggleButton widget is used to retrieve keybinding from user (key-press-event/key-release-event).

User presses togglebutton and presses some keys (Left Control + t, f.e.). Togglebutton`s event (key-press-event) returns "Control_L" and "t". Program saves this into string "t" and calls keybinder.bind("t", callback). User presses that hotkey and ... nothing happens. I found strange thing after some time of digging - keybinder understands "Control" (without _L/_R), "Alt" etc, and does not understand "Control_L", "Alt_L"...
Documentation says next:

Text from python-keybinder documentation:

```
bind(...)
    bind (keystring, callback, user_data) -> bool

    Keystring should be in the format understood by
    gtk.accelerator_parse. An example is '<Ctrl>space'.
```

Text from gtk/gtkaccelgroup.c:

- gtk_accelerator_parse:
  *
- Parses a string representing an accelerator. The
- format looks like "<Control>a" or "<Shift><Alt>F1" or
- "<Release>z" (the last one is for key release).
- The parser is fairly liberal and allows lower or upper case,
- and also abbreviations such as "<Ctl>" and "<Ctrl>".
- Key names are parsed using gdk_keyval_from_name().

Text from gdk/gdkkeynames.c:

- gdk_keyval_from_name:
  *
- Converts a key name to a key value.
  *
- The names are the same as those in the
- <gdk/gdkkeysyms.h> header file
- but without the leading "GDK_KEY_".

Ok, and at last text from gdk/gdkkeysyms.h:

```
205 #define GDK_KEY_Control_L 0xffe3
206 #define GDK_KEY_Control_R 0xffe4
```

How can I set and use keybinder without replacing "Control_L" to "Control", "Alt_L" to "Alt" and etc?

Upd: Linux, Python 2.4-2.7

Upd2: I want to see difference between "left control" and "right control" and use these keys as different buttons. How can I do this with gtk.accelerator_parse()? Is there a way?

Thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK offers [GtkCellRendererAccel](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellRendererAccel.html) for setting keybindings, this might be easier as you wont have to worry about converting between the two key description formats.

Comment: I use GtkCellRendererAccel for widgets on window already when window is opened and active, but most of times window is inactive and invisible. Global hotkey (maybe "system hotkey" will be more rightfully) is needed for these moments. GtkCellRendererAccel can`t assign global hotkey as I know, but maybe I am wrong. Could you show very small example or link to example/more precision docs?

Comment: Sorry I miss read your question the first time. GtkCellRendererAccel will display the hotkeys for you and provide a nice interface for users to set them. To convert the keyval and modifier properties to a string for [gtk.accelerator_parse](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkaccelgroup.html#function-gtk--accelerator-parse) you need to call [gtk.accelerator_name](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkaccelgroup.html#function-gtk--accelerator-name). You will need to mask the modifier against gtk.accelerator_get_default_mod_mask() if you stick with the toggle button.

Comment: Umm, yes. gtk.accelerator_name() returns string with all pressed keys (modifiers and key), but I want to see difference between "left control" and "right control" and use these keys as different buttons, not as the same (just "Control"). As I wrote earlier, Gtk must understand that Control_L and Control_R are different keys, but gtk.accelerator_parse() don`t understand that, even when I set mod mask to gtk.gdk.MODIFIER_MASK (all modifiers allowed).

Comment: Maybe my question slightly hazy, I`ll add some explanation to the Upd2.

Comment: Ah! I think I understand now, you're talking about two different calls to key-press-event, previously I thought you were refering to the modifer and keyval from one call. The short answer is no! However, you could do it by having a global variable to track Control L/R and then bind a function to "<Control>t" that checks the global and calls the appropriate function for that modifier. I guess You could track control L/R by watching all the key-press-events on the main window of your app.

Comment: > You could track control L/R by watching all the key-press-events on the main window of your app.

No, I can`t, because I haven`t main window (hidden) and haven`t focus on it (hidden/minimized). Any other program window can be active and focused. Key-press-event comes from X server, not from my main window.

I just don`t understand. Library (gtk) has all for work with "_L" and "_R" buttons as different buttons, but it does not do this.

Comment: If I understand correctly you set a global hotkey and then python-keybinder waits for it and then runs you callback. If that's the case I don't see how to distinguish between control L/R unless you somehow get all the key presses from the X server to track L/R as you cannot distinguish between then using gtk.accelerator_parse.

Comment: Ok, as I see X and Gtk maybe have different understanding of key codes and python-keybinder uses X way, not Gtk (or vice versa) or Gtk.Button has its own keys names. Anyway the answer is "No". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add an example to the accepted answer, here is the python code solved my problem:

```
>>> import gtk
>>> gtk.accelerator_name(ord(';'),gtk.gdk.MOD1_MASK)
'<Alt>semicolon'
```

The function documentation is at http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkaccelgroup.html#function-gtk--accelerator-name

The modifier constants are at: http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gdk-constants.html#gdk-modifier-constants.